# Time complexity of file modification?

Tags: file, data-structures, time-complexity

What is the time complexity (with respect to file size) of these file modifications?

- Overwriting
- Appending (inserting at the end)
- Prepending (inserting at the beginning)
- Inserting in the middle.

I expect that overwriting and appending are both fast. I can see prepending being fast enough, if files are structured like C++'s `deque`s, but I have never seen a language that allowed low-level prepending. I doubt inserting in the middle is fast, though I imagine there are data structures which could make it fast.

Comment: There is no "fast" or "slow" per se in time complexity. It's also a bit strange question since these depend highly on hardware, file systems, this and that.

Comment: The answers would depend at least on part on whether or not the OS supported non-contiguous files.

Comment: @Sami They don't exist as technical terms (though "superfast" is practically a technical term in numerical analysis), but I'm clearly not using them as technical terms. And a question that depends on the specs just means that a great answer would talk about how the most common specs handle it, with an exceptional answer discussing what else is out there.

Answer (score 5):

In most file systems:

- Overwriting a file is O(n), where n is the number of bytes to be written.
- Appending a file is O(n), where n is the number of bytes to be written.
- Prepending is O(n + m), where n is the number of bytes to be written, and m is the number of bytes currently in the file.
- Insertion is O(n + m), where n is the number of bytes to be written, and m is the number of bytes currently in the file.

The O(n + m) for insertion is the worst case. When you're inserting into a file, you have to move all the bytes currently in the file from the insertion point down to make a hole for n bytes to be inserted. So if you have:

```
This is a test system.
```

And you want to insert "of the emergency broadcast" after "test", then you first have to make a hole for the inserted text:

```
This is a test                            system.
```

And then insert the new text:

```
This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.
```

In this way, a file is conceptually very much like an array. If you want to insert something at the front or in the middle, you have to make a hole for it. If you want to remove something, you have to fill the voided space.

There are file systems that let you patch files together from non-contiguous blocks. That is, you could have something that is logically like:

```
<pointer to "This is a test" chunk>
<pointer to "of the emergency broadcast" chunk>
<pointer to "system." chunk>
```

The file system takes care of splitting and coalescing chunks as necessary. Those file systems aren't exactly rare, but that functionality typically isn't used by normal programs.

Comment: Do you have sources/references for file contents being treated like arrays in most filesystems?

Comment: @leewz: I didn't say that file systems treat file contents like arrays. I said that, conceptually, you can think of prepending, adding, overwriting, and appending in much the same way that you would do things in an array. File systems typically have two access modes: sequential, in which the file is conceptually a stream, or random access in which it's more like an array. See any file system API reference to verify this. Most programming languages' I/O libraries have sequential access methods and random access methods.